# Image uploading to Facebook using C# 

Tags: .net, facebook, c#-4.0, facebook-c#-sdk

I am developing an application using C#. My requirement is to upload the photo to the profile of a user at Facebook.

I have used the library from the article *[Facebook Album](http://facebooksdk.blogspot.in/2011/04/facebook-album.html)*, but the method is asking for an access token. How do I get the access token from Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

Read this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/.

Also read the documentation of your library they must have some method to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

In the blog post you mentioned, there is a link how to get the access 
token, *[FacebookLoginHelper](http://facebooksdk.blogspot.com/2011/03/facebookloginhelper.html)*.

Comment: The link is suggesting to create an application on facebook & register the same. Do i need to do this?

Comment: Yes you have to do this, your vistor have to login via OAuth to grant your application access to his facebook data.